# OAuth Twitter Login sequence

Tags: google-app-engine, twitter-oauth, python-2.x

Different websites have different sequence for oauth. E.g., http://oauth.net/core/diagram.png has 7 interactions! During implementation based on existing libraries (listed below), we don't see steps B and C happening at all.

Questions are:

1. Is it OK to skip B and C (per the above diagram). Or there are bugs
   in the library.
2. For step E, do we need to recompute all parameters except for oauth_verifier and oauth_token that are received in step D
3. Is it correct to assume that step C helps avoid user entering PIN manually

Development Environment Information:

- Development language: Python (2.5)
- Platform: Google App Engine
- Reference libraries are listed below:

(a) [http://sa-jtwitter-bot.googlecode.com/hg/oauthtwitter.py][2],

(b) [http://python-twitter.googlecode.com/hg/twitter.py][3]

(c) Actual code run when user goes to say http://myapp.com/twitter/authrequest, and for callback: http://myapp.com/twitter/authresponse, is taken from
[http://popdevelop.com/2010/07/an-example-on-how-to-use-oauth-and-python-to-connect-to-twitter][4]

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not specific to the development environment mentioned by you but is generic.

**Ans 1.** You cannot skip step B and C unless you already have access token for that particular user. Actually in step B and C, authentication/authorization popup opens from the service provider. The user then enters his/her credentials and Allow authorization to user app. Next, in your callback, you again ask for access token on behalf of the user. Once you receive the access token, you can make request to service provider to fetch information/data. In case, you are storing the access token in your DB, then you can skip above steps and directly request the data using access token but then few service providers ask you to refresh the access token after some time, which involves one more call by passing old access token to fetch new access token (e.g. Yahoo)

**Ans 2.** You need to recompute oauth_signature, oauth_timestamp, oauth_nonce everytime to make a request because this parameters are used/generated for each request, for others you can use the previous values.

**Ans 3.** Step C is there to get authorization from the user for the actions/scope your application is asking for.